# Pandas dataframe to excel problems?

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas, dataframe

I am new to python and this is the first large program I've attempted to build. I am trying to scrape data from a folder with 3 different PDFs. Due to the vast differences in PDF styling I use regex to find keywords in the pages to decide which style of code I use to scrape the data into a pandas dataframe. Everything seems to work on its own. Gets the proper data and puts it into a dataframe. But when I want to append that data into a master dataframe called dffinal the data either isn't getting there, or it is not getting put into the excel spreadsheet. I've posted the most of the code below. If anyone can help me figure out what exactly is going wrong and how to fix it that would be great. Thanks.

The way it should work is this: The user selects the directory where the PDFs are. User selects the directory where the Excel spreadsheet is if it already exists or is suppose to be when created. Then goes through a few conditionals to figure out which style of data needs to be scraped. Then it takes that data, turns it into a pandas dataframe, and appends that dataframe to a master dataframe. After all the PDFs have been scraped the master dataframe will be used to fill out the excel spreadsheet that was created or selected. I hope I explained that well enough to understand what I'm trying to do with the code below.

```
import subprocess
import time
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter.ttk import Progressbar
import PyPDF2
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import xlsxwriter

column_names = ['Date', 'Vendor', 'Item Number', 'Item Description', 'Quantity', 'Price', 'Tax', 'Cash Sale','Discount Amt', 'Amt Charged', 'Ordered By']
dffinal = pd.DataFrame(columns=column_names)


window = Tk()
window.geometry('500x200')
window.wm_title('I.T.E.D. Converter')


def browsepath():
    foldername = filedialog.askdirectory()
    e1.delete(0, END)
    e1.insert(END, foldername)


def browsespd():
    filename = filedialog.askdirectory()
    e2.delete(0, END)
    e2.insert(END, filename)


l1 = Label(text='Use the browse buttons below to select the PDF folder and Excel folders.')
l1.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=10)


instructions1 = Label(window, text='PDF Directory: ')
instructions1.grid(row=1, column=0)
instructions2 = Label(window, text='Excel File Directory: ')
instructions2.grid(row=3, column=0)
instructions3 = Label(window, text='If no Excel file exists, one will be created for you.')
instructions3.grid(row=5, column=0, columnspan=2)

pdf_folder = StringVar()
e1 = Entry(window, textvariable=pdf_folder)
e1.grid(row=2, column=0)
excel_file = StringVar()
e2 = Entry(window, textvariable=excel_file)
e2.grid(row=4, column=0)


progress = Progressbar(window, orient=HORIZONTAL, length=500, mode='determinate')


def bar():
    progress['value'] = 2
    window.update_idletasks()
    time.sleep(0.1)

    progress['value'] = 5
    window.update_idletasks()
    time.sleep(0.1)

    progress['value'] = 10
    window.update_idletasks()
    time.sleep(0.1)

    progress['value'] = 20
    window.update_idletasks()
    time.sleep(0.1)

    progress['value'] = 30
    window.update_idletasks()
    time.sleep(0.1)

    progress['value'] = 40
    window.update_idletasks()
    time.sleep(0.1)

    progress['value'] = 50
    window.update_idletasks()
    time.sleep(0.1)

    progress['value'] = 60
    window.update_idletasks()
    time.sleep(0.1)

    progress['value'] = 70
    window.update_idletasks()
    time.sleep(0.1)

    progress['value'] = 80
    window.update_idletasks()
    time.sleep(0.1)

    progress['value'] = 90
    window.update_idletasks()
    time.sleep(0.1)
    progress['value'] = 100


progress.grid(row=6, column=0, columnspan=10)

b1 = Button(window, text='Start', width=12, command=lambda: [check_for_xlsx(), add_data(), bar()])
b1.grid(row=7, column=0)
b2 = Button(window, text='Close', width=12, command=window.destroy)
b2.grid(row=7, column=3)
b3 = Button(window, text='Browse', width=8, command=browsepath)
b3.grid(row=2, column=1)
b4 = Button(window, text='Browse', width=8, command=browsespd)
b4.grid(row=4, column=1)


def create_excel():
    path = excel_file.get()
    filename = 'Invoices.xlsx'
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(path + filename)
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('Invoice Data')
    worksheet.write('A1', 'Date')
    worksheet.write('B1', 'Vendor')
    worksheet.write('C1', 'Item Number')
    worksheet.write('D1', 'Item Description')
    worksheet.write('E1', 'Quantity')
    worksheet.write('F1', 'Price')
    worksheet.write('G1', 'Tax')
    worksheet.write('H1', 'Cash Sale')
    worksheet.write('I1', 'Discount Amt')
    worksheet.write('J1', 'Amt Charged')
    worksheet.write('K1', 'Ordered By')
    workbook.close()


def add_data():
    df = dffinal
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Invoices.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
    # try to open an existing workbook
    writer.book = load_workbook('Invoices.xlsx')
    # copy existing sheets
    writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in writer.book.worksheets)
    # read existing file
    reader = pd.read_excel(r'Invoices.xlsx')
    # write out the new sheet
    df.to_excel(writer, index=False, header=False, startrow=len(reader)+1)

    writer.save()
    writer.close()


def convert_pdf():
    directory = pdf_folder.get()
    for name in directory:
        if name.endswith('.pdf'):
            obj = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(name)
            numpages = obj.getNumPages()
            search1 = "Keyword that identifies PDF"
            search2 = "Keyword that identifies PDF"
            search3 = "Keyword that identifies PDF"
            for i in range(0, numpages):
                pdf = name
                output = subprocess.check_output(['pdftotext', '-layout', pdf, '-']).decode()
                pages = output.strip('\f').split('\f')
                page = pages[-1]
                lookup1 = re.search(search1, page)
                lookup2 = re.search(search2, page)
                lookup3 = re.search(search3, page)
                if lookup1:
                    # does some stuff to get the proper data

                    key = ['Date', 'Vendor', 'Tax', 'Cash Sale', 'Discount Amt', 'Amt Charged', 'Ordered By']
                    lst1 = [date, vendor, tax, cash_payment, disc_amt, amt_charged, name]
                    # Create a zip object from two lists
                    zipbObj = zip(key, lst1)
                    # Create a dictionary from zip object
                    dict_list = dict(zipbObj)

                    key_item = ['LN#', 'Quantity', 'Amt Shipped', 'Item Number', 'Price', 'Total Price','Item Description']
                    values = items
                    dict_items = {x: list(y) for x, y in zip(key_item, zip(*values))}
                    dict_items.update(dict_list)
                    df = pd.DataFrame(dict_items)
                    df.drop(['LN#', 'Amt Shipped', 'Unit', 'Total Price'])
                    dffinal.append(df)

                elif lookup2:
                    # does some other stuff to gather data for the different PDF

                    key = ['Date', 'Vendor', 'Tax', 'Cash Sale', 'Discount', 'Amt Charged', 'Ordered By']
                    lst1 = [date, vendor, tax, cash_payment, disc_amt, amt_charged, name]

                    zipbObj = zip(key, lst1)
                    dict_list = dict(zipbObj)
                    key_item = ['Item Number', 'Description', 'Quantity', 'Amt Shipped', 'Price', 'Unit', 'Total Price']
                    values = items
                    dict_items = {x: list(y) for x, y in zip(key_item, zip(*values))}
                    dict_items.update(dict_list)
                    df = pd.DataFrame(dict_items)
                    df.drop(['Amt Shipped', 'Unit', 'Total Price'])
                    dffinal.append(df)
                elif lookup3:
                    # does some stuff with regex to gather the correct data


                    key = ['Date', 'Vendor', 'Tax', 'Amt Charged', 'Ordered By', 'Cash Payment']
                    lst1 = [date, vendor, tax, amt_charged, name, cash_payment]
                    zipbObj = zip(key, lst1)
                    dict_list = dict(zipbObj)

                    key_item = ['LN#', 'Item Number', 'Description', 'Quantity', 'Amt Shipped', 'Price', 'Total Price']
                    values = items
                    dict_items = {x: list(y) for x, y in zip(key_item, zip(*values))}
                    dict_items.update(dict_list)
                    df = pd.DataFrame(dict_items)
                    df.drop(['Amt Shipped', 'Unit', 'LN#'])
                    dffinal.append(df)
                else:
                    return 'There are no matching PDFs in this folder'


def check_for_xlsx():
    path = excel_file.get()
    filename = 'Invoices.xlsx'
    if filename not in path:
        create_excel()
    else:
        convert_pdf()


window.mainloop()
```

Comment: can you check if the pdf data is being appended in final dataframe by simply checking `df.tail()` ? and I would recommend using pandas api for writing excel file as you are already using a pandas dataframe (i.e. master dataframe) to populate excel.

Comment: I went through everything again, piece by piece, and for some reason I'm not getting any input to the final dataframe. The inner workings to get the text works by itself, but I am not getting past the for loop conditionals to decide which style of scraping to use. It appears as though it is not finding the pdfs in the directory?